# why my .htaccess redirecting subdomain1 to the domain1 takes to domain2 hosted in same server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have hosted two sites e.g http://www.one.com and http://www.two.com in the same server. (Controlling them with apache2, virtual hosts files, .htaccess)

two.com has subdomains touch.two.com and support.two.com

```
http://www.one.com is the default site which uses 000-default.conf
http://www.two.com uses two.conf
http://www.touch.two.com uses touch.two.conf
http://www.suport.two.com uses support.two.conf
```

I want to redirect any subdomain for two.com to http://www.two.com except for touch and support, I have this below .htaccess file but all subdomain directs to http://www.one.com why ?

I have a .htaccess file for http://www.two.com which is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # Redirect anything except touch.two.com and support.two.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(touch|support)\.two\.com$ [NC]
    # Redirect to two.com, preserving the URI
    RewriteRule .*\.two\. http://www.two.com [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Show all the vhosts files.

Comment: vhost file doesn't have any rule it's just the default with urls thats it. Assume there is no http://www.one.com then also why the rewrite rule doesnt work ?